# Why 'user' is always 'null' in onAuthStateChanged (Firebase 9 + Vue 3 + Pinia)?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, pinia

I have a problem with Firebase's `onAuthStateChanged` which no matter what I've tried always returns the `user` as `null` after page reload. The required behavior is to auto-login user after page reload.

That is the first time I use the modular version of Firebase 9 and Pinia as a store.

I've already tried to use `setPersistence` (LOCAL) but the result is the same.

I'm stuck for the whole day and cannot figure out why it's not working.

I'd be grateful for pointing out what I'm missing there.

Packages I use in my `package.json`:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^9.6.11",
    "pinia": "^2.0.13",
    "vue": "^3.2.13",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.3"
  }
```

`main.ts` file:

```js
import { createApp, App as VueApp } from 'vue';
import { createPinia } from 'pinia';
import { auth } from '@/firebase';
import { onAuthStateChanged, User } from 'firebase/auth';
import { useAuthStore } from '@/store/auth';

let app: VueApp;

function initializeApp(user: User | null) {
  app = createApp(App)
    .use(createPinia())
    .use(router);

  if (user) {
    // PROMEM IS THERE -> user IS ALWAYS null
    // I want to set logged user before app is mounted
    const authStore = useAuthStore();
    authStore.handleAuthStateChange(user);
  }

  app.mount('#app');
}

onAuthStateChanged(
  auth,
  (user: User | null) => {
    // PROMEM IS THERE -> user IS ALWAYS null
    if (!app) {
      initializeApp(user);
    } else {
      const authStore = useAuthStore();
      authStore.handleAuthStateChange(user);
    }
  },
  (error: Error) => {
    log.error(`Main AuthStateChange handler failed with error`, error);
  },
);
```

`firebase.ts` file:

```js
import { FirebaseApp, initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { Auth, initializeAuth, debugErrorMap } from 'firebase/auth';
import { firebaseConfig } from '@/config';

export const app: FirebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth: Auth = initializeAuth(app, { errorMap: debugErrorMap });
```

`auth.ts` -> store file:

```js
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import { LoginCredentials, SignUpCredentials } from '@/types/auth';
import { FirebaseAuthenticationService, AuthenticationService } from '@/service/AuthenticationService';
import { auth as firebaseAuth } from '@/firebase';
import { log } from '@/service/LoggerService';

export interface AuthStoreUser {
  uid: string,
  email: string | null
}

export type MaybeAuthStoreUser = AuthStoreUser | null;

export interface AuthStoreState {
  user: AuthStoreUser | null,
}

export const authStoreFactory = ($auth: AuthenticationService) => defineStore('auth', {
  state: () => ({
    user: null,
  } as AuthStoreState),
  getters: {
    isUserLoggedIn(): boolean {
      return !!this.user;
    },
  },
  actions: {
    async signUpUser(credentials: SignUpCredentials) {
      const createdUser = await $auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(credentials);
    },
    async loginUser(credentials: LoginCredentials) {
      const user = await $auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(credentials);
    },
    async setCurrentUser(user: AuthStoreUser) {
      this.user = user;
    },
    async clearCurrentUser() {
      this.user = null;
    },
    async logoutUser() {
      await $auth.signOut();
    },
    async sendPasswordResetEmail(email: string) {
      await $auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email);
    },
    async handleAuthStateChange(user: MaybeAuthStoreUser) {
      if (user) {
        log.debug(`Logging in user from authStateChange handler`);
        this.setCurrentUser(user);
      } else {
        log.debug(`AuthStateChange handler did not receive current user.`);
        this.clearCurrentUser();
      }
    },
  },
});

export const useAuthStore = () => {
  const $auth = new FirebaseAuthenticationService(firebaseAuth);
  return authStoreFactory($auth)();
};
```

Comment: You can expect user to always be null after the page first loads or is refreshed. The user object will arrive some time later in a second callback if the user is signed in.

Comment: @DougStevenson, but 'some time later in a second callback' never happens. I have login form -> user is signing in -> user is redirected to dashboard page -> everything is okay until reloading the page. After that user is null and the callback is not called 'some time later. Any other ideas or advices? :/

Comment: @DougStevenson: `onAuthStateChanged` will only fire for the first time once its done restoring the credentials from local storage. So if that fires with `null`, the restore failed (or there was nothing to restore).

Comment: I made a test and switched back to a namespaced version of firebase instead of a modular one. Code works as expected and the user is properly signed in after reloading the page. So I missed something or misunderstood firebase's documentation with respect to the modular library. If anyone is able to find a mistake in the code I provided in question I would appreciate it. For now, the namespaced version is the way to go for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally solved this problem by adding `persistence` option to `initializeAuth`. And [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence) for this part is misleading and does not explain properly how it should be done with `initializeAuth` method...

This is how `auth` should be initialized in `firebase.ts` file:

```js
import { firebaseConfig } from '@/config';
import { FirebaseApp, initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { 
  Auth, 
  initializeAuth, 
  debugErrorMap,
  indexedDBLocalPersistence, 
  browserLocalPersistence } from 'firebase/auth';

export const app: FirebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth: Auth = initializeAuth(app, { 
  persistence: [indexedDBLocalPersistence, browserLocalPersistence],
  errorMap: debugErrorMap 
});
```

It is interesting what I've found in [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence):

> The **default for web browser and React Native apps is local** (provided the browser supports this storage mechanism, eg. 3rd party cookies/data are enabled) whereas it is none for Node.js backend apps.

And this is what I've found in `auth-public.d.ts` file:

```js
export declare interface Dependencies {
    /**
     * Which {@link Persistence} to use. If this is an array, the first
     * `Persistence` that the device supports is used. The SDK searches for an
     * existing account in order and, if one is found in a secondary
     * `Persistence`, the account is moved to the primary `Persistence`.
     *
     * If no persistence is provided, the SDK falls back on
     * {@link inMemoryPersistence}.
     */
    persistence?: Persistence | Persistence[];
    // other stuff
}
```

> If no persistence is provided, **the SDK falls back on inMemoryPersistence**

And `inMemoryPersistence` means `NONE` persistence. And that was cause of my problem.